# Default template for ComboBox: How does IsEditable switch TextBox and Contentpresenter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox

I am using `ComboBox` in WPF but there is one behavior that I don't understand: here is the link of the [default style/template of `ComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) . When `IsEditable` is True, the `TextBox` shows and the user can type text to search. I didn't quite understand this so I was checking the code:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                        Margin="3,3,23,3"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
      </ContentPresenter>
      <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
               Style="{x:Null}"
               Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               Margin="3,3,23,3"
               Focusable="True"
               Background="Transparent"
               Visibility="Hidden"
               IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />
```

It seems there are two visual components overlapping and `IsEditable` switches between them by setting the `Visibility`. [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) verifies that: "**When IsEditable is equal to false, the ComboBox uses a ContentPresenter to display the currently selected item; when IsEditable is equal to true, a TextBox is used for this purpose instead. Note that a TextBox only displays plain text, and that a ComboBoxItem may include non-plain text content, such as images.**" My question is, in the `TextBox`, where does it define the text? The `Template` (ComboBoxTextBox) doesn't assign the Text. I was asking because I am trying to make the `TextBox` to display the same info (if that's ever possible) as the `ContentPresenter` (i.e., as when `IsEditable` is False), whose template I understand is binding to the `Template` I assign.

Comment: are you trying to have a dropdown for a combo box? or want to switch between editable and read only via the template?

Comment: @pushpraj I am trying to let the `TextBox` (which is only visible when `IsEditable` is True because otherwise the `ContentPreseter` is visible as my second link suggests) have the same `ItemTemplate` I set. Because by default, if `IsEditable` is true, the `TextBox` shows and the `ItemTemplate` doesn't apply to it. It uses `ToString` function of the selected item, or display the item's property (`ToString`) value if I set `TextSearch.TextPath` on the `ComboBox`. Neither of them is what I want because I want the editable `TextBox` do display more information like I defined in the `ItemTemplate`

Comment: @pushpraj So I am trying to understand how the default template works hoping I can change it when I understand. But so far I don't see any setting for the text of the `TextBox`.

Comment: @tete  Firstly "the TextBox shows and the user can type text to search." is not correct. It is only make the user can type text. You can add `Text="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.Text}"` to `<TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"/>` ,they have the same result. So i guess there are something default setting.yep, just guess..

Answer (score -1):

here is a bare basic template for textbox for you with just the text editing part

so setting IsReadOnly="True" will make it like a ContentPresenter otherwise it is editable like a textbox

```
<TextBox Text="edit me">
    <TextBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TextBox.Template>
</TextBox>
```

you can customize it for your needs